# IndexOptimize is successful, but sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats still shows huge fragmentation

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren, fragmentation, index-maintenance

I'm working on a project that requires a database shrink. Following the shrink, I checked `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` and can see a lot of my indexes are over 99% fragmented (`avg_fragmentation_in_percent`).

In response to this, I executed `IndexOptimize` by Ola Hallengren, with the following code:

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[IndexOptimize]
    @Databases = 'Dynamic.Migrate',
    @FragmentationLow = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE',
    @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
    @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
    @FillFactor = '80',
    @UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
    @StatisticsSample = '100',
    @LogToTable = 'Y'
```

This completed successfully, but when I check `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` again, the `avg_fragmentation_in_percent` values have not changed, and state my indexes are still fragmented by over 99%.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: More details please. Is this an index or a heap you are looking at (index id)? How many pages does the index have?

Comment: Related: [Why not rebuild indexes with page count <1000?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/87417/1192)

Comment: Please read [What Can Cause Index to be Still Fragmented After Rebuild](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28182.sql-server-in-depth-what-can-cause-index-to-be-still-fragmented-after-rebuild.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from Ola Hallengren's [SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) documentation:

> MinNumberOfPages
>
> Set a size, in pages; indexes with fewer number of pages are skipped
>   for index maintenance. The default is 1000 pages. This is based on
>   Microsoft’s recommendation.
>
> IndexOptimize checks page_count in sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats to
>   determine the size of the index.

Therefore, the indexes you mentioned are still fragmented after executing `IndexOptimize` were most likely skipped for having fewer pages than the minimum of 1000 pages since you didn't change that value in your code.

Comment: Can't believe that I missed this information! Thanks for the heads up, can confirm that all the indexes still fragmented at < 1000 pages.